# Android: Most efficient way to record time

Tags: android, timer

I'm making a simple quiz app where it will tell them the time it took to answer the question. 
When they click the button, it'll change a text to tell them how long it took them.

I wanted to know the most efficient way to implement the timer. I read that you could use Timer, but should be avoided as it uses a new Thread. Instead, I searched and read that you could use the Handler.

Is there any other method that I should consider?

Thanks ahead of time for your help.

Comment: How about just storing a timestamp when they start and once again when they answer the question and then taking the difference?

Comment: Thanks for the response. From doing a quick read, I have some concerns before deciding on timestamp. I should have been more clear. I want to get a timer down to the centiSeconds.

Can I get values in the centiSeconds? It seems like I can use it to get the time in the hr/min/seconds.

Comment: *edit. I've been doing some quick read and it seems like I can use this.

Would you recommend timestamp over a handler? Which one would utilize less memory or is the difference insignificant?

Comment: I ended up using your method with System.nanoTime(). Works great! Thanks a lot.